# How to store the output of method?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am looking for easy way to store the output of the method in some sort of variable so that it can be used by another class.

For example:

```
partial class Form1 {
    public string orderNumber() {
        string ord="ORD"+get_next_id()+DateTime.Now.Year;
        return ord;
    }
}
```

In an instance of `Form1` user enter the purchase details such as name, address... and when user clicks add entry button, the details is saved in the database with `ordernumber` generated by above code. In meantime when user click add entry, it kills the current form and bring up the another form which uses the `ordernumber` generated earlier. When I do like

```
Form1 m=new Form1();
```

and do something like(following is pseudo code)

```
m.orderNumber=string orderNUm.
```

It generates different order number which I don't want. I want to use the ordernumber that was saved in the database by the `Form1`.

I want to store that ord somewhere so that I can pass it to another class.

Comment: No idea how can I store it..

Comment: Have you heard of _variables_?

Comment: I know man, but I have different scenario..

Comment: I just noticed that you said "some sort of variable". So now I don't understand the question. Variables are where you store things in a program.

Comment: @Barmar ok let me make you clear. In form1 user enter the purchase details such as name, address... and when user clicks add entry button, the details is saved in the database with ordernumber generated by above code. In meantime when user click add entry, it kills the current form and bring up the another form which uses the ordernumber generated earlier. When I do like form1 m = new Form1() and m.orderNumber = string orderNUm. It generates different order number which I don't want. I want to use the ordernumber that was saved in the database by the form1.

Comment: sorry I didn't put question clearly because of lack of time..

Comment: @AmritSharma If you don't have a clear question you can't get a clear answer.

Answer (score 5):

Another class can use the result simply by calling the method itself:

```
public class A
{
    public string orderNumber()
    {
        string ord = "ORD" + get_next_id() + DateTime.Now.Year;
        return ord;
    }
}

public class B
{
    public void DoSomeWork()
    {
        A a = new A();
        string result = a.orderNumber();
    }
}
```

The notion of "storing it somewhere" feels like the concept of a global variable.  While one can accomplish essentially the same thing, that is to be discouraged as that does not represent object oriented design principals.

Just to understand *how* you could do that in C# (you *should not do this*), you could do:

```
static public SharedStorage
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
}

// Somewhere in your code

SharedStorage.OrderNumber = a.orderNumber();

// Somewhere else in your code

string orderNumber = SharedStorage.OrderNumber;
```

If you want to set an order number on an instance *once* and then use it going forward, you could put the logic in the constructor:

```
public class A
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; private set; }
    public A()
    {
        OrderNumber = "ORD" + get_next_id() + DateTime.Now.Year;
    }
}

// Somewhere else in your code

A a = new A();
string orderNumber = a.OrderNumber;
```

Comment: +1 sir, if you don't mind, why you said that _"you should not do this"_ what is or will be the bad practice. can you give a brief reason? :)

Comment: Ahhhhh mutable state. How evil you are. While the simplicity of a single filing cabinet that everyone uses seems so tempting at first soon it runs into problems.  
"What the hell? Why is my file the value of 4? It should be 5?" cried Geoff.
"Oh sorry, I was using that too" said Sandra.
"Hey we're going to move marketing down the street, so we'll need to take that filing cabinet with us"
"But we need it, if you move down the street, we'll need to move with you!".

Comment: @spajce: Quite simply because it becomes confusing as the code grows and becomes more complex who put a value in shared state and what that value really means for the program.  Beyond that, using object oriented design patterns allows you to create code faster that is more robust and more easily adapted to changing circumstances.

Comment: "Do we really need to share all of that data with everyone?". How about Geoff and Sandra just talk to each other about the data they need to share. Sandra can just take a reference to Geoff (as she's his boss) and Sandra can query Geoff when she needs to know what he's up to. Geoff can raise events to let Sandra know what he's up to. And marketing can just use their own filing cabinet that they don't share with anyone else.

Comment: i am not who created the question sir and i hope that OP get your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly basic stuff, but add this to the top of the class:

```
public string OrderCode;
```

Next add `OrderCode = ord;` above the `return ord;` line

Now whenever someone needs the ordercode they just make a call to `<YourClass>.OrderCode`

However, they could just call the method itself to get the order number as it is public.

PS:  the `orderNumber` method doesn't follow c# conventions. a) it should be properly capitalized (OrderNumber) and b) a more meaningful name would be GetOrderNumber